# Are there (documented) rules for the behavior of closing duplicate questions or why does it (esp. with dupehammer) show inconsistent behavior?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I noted certain differences in the behavior when closing question for being a duplicate. I’m talking about using the gold badge for immediate closing and don’t know how much it also relates to the non-gold badge owner’s close voting:

- Sometimes the message is “This question already has an answer here” but sometimes the message is “This question is an exact duplicate of”
- Sometimes the users, who voted for closing before, are listed before my name, sometimes they disappear completely, showing me as the sole closer
- Sometimes, alternative questions from the other close votes are shown in the message, making it a list of questions having answers to the closed question, sometimes only the question specified by myself is linked (while the other links still are removed from the comments); this might be connected to one of the previous bullets

Is there a rationale for this different behavior? Can I somehow predict what will happen when I hit the “close” button?

After all, being an identical question or just having an appropriate answer are two completely different things and it would surprise me if the system is smart enough to recognize the difference from the contents whereas sometimes even humans struggle.

And sometimes the “duplicate” suggestions made by other users produced valuable links I don’t want to erase with my close votes. I once found myself re-adding the links to the comments manually, so if there is a rule to when these links are retained and when not, I would like to know it.

Another thing that bothers me is that not only valid link suggestions of other users (and the user names) might get lost when closing a question, sometimes the names of users who voted for closing the question, *but for different reasons* appear in the message as if they all voted for closing the question for being a duplicate as I did. That’s a nice support, so it doesn’t look like a single guy closed the question with a dupehammer, but it doesn’t feel right. This might be a general problem with how close votes giving different reasons are merged when the question eventually gets closed.

Comment: "exact dupe" is old school, it has been changed about a year ago. See [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) at MSE

Comment: @gnat: [disproved](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29220865/2711488), closed one week ago, showing the message. That’s why I’m asking, the behavior looks indeterminate.

Comment: very interesting! wonder if old-school banner somehow is correlated with [meta-tag:dupehammer] closures (your example was closed by hammer)

Comment: @gnat: as hinted in the question, I was basically talking about dupehammer closures as I mostly do such votes in my knowledge area and noticed the inconsistent behavior. Especially as noticing the inconsistent behavior is easier when the closure happens immediately after my vote…

Comment: incidentally, I have _some_ collection of non-hammer dupes. I briefly checked about dozen of [recent ones here at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=duplicate%3ayes) and it looks like only dupehammer does "exact" banner. Regular closures, as well as those [approved by asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/165773) all show "has an answer"

Comment: You forgot one behaviour that happened with me before: You ask a question that was asked a long time ago (over 2 months). Then, someone closes it and it says it `"Already has an answer on [...]"`, when the other question **has no answers at all**.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel: normally, you can close a question as duplicate only when the other question has either an accepted or at least one upvoted answer. But afaik, being upvoted does not prevent an answer from being deleted by the owner. So there is a possible scenario how this can happen…

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: And a question can always be dupe-closed to a question by the same author. That's for reining in flagrant self-duplication.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't get it...

Comment: @gnat: the new title looks too narrow as I asked about other inconsistencies as well. And I wanted to emphasize the *inconsistencies* as the behavior only occurs sometimes…

Comment: yeah I was also unsure about that (feel free to rollback if you feel strongly against it). I failed to make a fuller synopsis into the title, so I decided to focus on part that looked most prominently troublesome, hoping that readers will find the rest in the text

Comment: The “exact duplicate” message happened to [appear again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33386786/2711488) though in this case, it’s nailing it.