# After dupe-hammering, other close-voters are not displayed

Tags: support, dupehammer, deleted-comments

As so often, I closed a few questions with my Mjölnir superpowers. However, I noticed something odd: I was the only user being attributed in the message, even though others seemed to have close-voted before me. There were "*possible duplicate of …*" comments, and when selecting the target in the close dialog I was shown the choice(s) of the other voters. But afterwards, it appeared as if they never existed! They can't be found in the timeline either. **What happened to them?**

Some examples:

- [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44197479/timeline)
- [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44188345/timeline)
- [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44188356/timeline) even still shows the link to the other target suggestion in the sidebar
- [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44190720/timeline) is fine though

Maybe someone is working on the [Misleading dupehammer message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344386/1048572)? Can some mod still see the deleted comments and possibly even confirm the other votes?

Comment: [This support request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289101/1048572) also reports inconsistent behaviour: "*Sometimes the users, who voted for closing before, are listed before my name, sometimes they disappear completely, showing me as the sole closer*"

Comment: Are you sure thee were really close votes or just flags?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Uh, no. How do I see the difference?

Comment: You see a difference if the close dialog pops up, there are indications of other close votes. If they were just flags, these don't appear.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess I overlooked that, I didn't pay much attention to the first screen of the dialog. I'm pretty certain though the suggested target was indicated as another user's choice, but I might be misremembering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are deleted comments that were created stating that the post is a duplicate.  Each one of these posts was flagged as duplicates by users without the privilege to close yet.

Since they don't have close votes, their names don't appear in the list of people who voted to close the post. The close votes privileges are given at 3k+ rep, once a user hits that rep then their name would appear.

Comment: Ah, I always forget about flags.